# Cómo modificar la intercalación en una vista existente

Tags: sql-server

Al intentar cambiar la intercalación de una base de datos completa 
me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Msg 5075, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 95 El objeto 'vista_saldos4'
>   depende de la clasificación de la base de datos. La intercalación de
>   la base de datos no se puede cambiar si un objeto vinculado a un
>   esquema depende de ella. Elimine las dependencias de la intercalación
>   de la base de datos y luego vuelva a intentar la operación.

Como puedo cambiar la intercalación de una `View`?, tengo esto pero no funciona

```
ALTER VIEW vista_saldos4 AS SELECT name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que eliminar todos los objetos que usan esa vista, solo después podrás cambiarla. Una vez que hagas el cambio, tendrás que recrear los objetos.